# Using pandas to groupby and automatically fill data

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe using pandas:

[image]
The header column elements that have a nan should say the last word founded. Thus, the column header should be:

nan Ciclo Indoor  Ciclo Indoor  Ciclo Indoor Ciclo Indoor  Body Pump  Body Pump  ....

After this, I want to groupby by the sport (cycle indoor, etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with `method='ffill'` (`.ffill`), but it does not work with `Index`, so need [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) first:

```
cols = [np.nan, 'Ciclo Indoor', np.nan, np.nan, 'Body Pump', np.nan, np.nan]
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,1,2,1,0,1]], columns = cols)
print (df)

   NaN  Ciclo Indoor  NaN  NaN  Body Pump  NaN  NaN
0    1             0    1    2          1    0    1

df.columns = df.columns.to_series().ffill()
print (df)
   NaN  Ciclo Indoor  Ciclo Indoor  Ciclo Indoor  Body Pump  Body Pump  \
0    1             0             1             2          1          0   

   Body Pump  
0          1
```

Last [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by column names `axis=1` and `level=0` and aggregate `sum` or `mean`...

```
df1 = df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum()
print (df1)
   Body Pump  Ciclo Indoor
0          2             3
```